# How do I omit the title from the shortened citations in BibLaTeX-Chicago?

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I am writing a history essay using biblatex-chicago. My TA said that since I am only referencing one work by each author I should omit the title of the work from the shortened citations (each citation after the first one)

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Allows UTF8 input.

%Citation Stuff
\usepackage[german,american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes,natbib,isbn=false,backend=biber,url=false]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Example,
title={The Necronomicon},
author={Alhazred, Abdul},
publisher={Miskatonic University Press},
year={738},
city={Arkham}
}

@Book{Tooze,
 author = {Tooze, Adam},
 title = {The Wages of Destruction: The Making and Breaking of the Nazi Economy},
 publisher = {Allen Lane},
 year = {2006},
 address = {London},
 isbn = {9780713995664}
 }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

``Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn''\autocite[6]{Example}

I realized I needed a citation in between them, and didn't want to take the time to make another fake entry\autocite[314]{Tooze}

``That is not dead which can eternal lie, yet with stranger aeons, even Death may die.''\autocite[616]{Example}

\end{document}
```

Which vies the output:

“Ph’nglui mglw’nafh Cthulhu R’lyeh wgah’nagl fhtagn”<sup>1</sup>

I realized I needed a citation in between them, and didn’t want to take
the time to make another fake entry<sup>2</sup>

“That is not dead which can eternal lie, yet with stranger aeons, even
Death may die.”<sup>3</sup>

---

1. Abdul Alhazred, The Necronomicon (Miskatonic University Press, 738), 6.
2. Adam Tooze, The Wages of Destruction: The Making and Breaking of the Nazi Economy (London: Allen Lane, 2006), 314.
3. Alhazred, The Necronomicon, 616.

You see how it automatically shortens the author name, and omits the publisher and year of publication? How do I get it to also omit the title? I know there is a **shorttitle** field I can use to enter a shorter form of the title, which I'll do if I can't get an answer to this (Or the answer is 'this can't be done'), which will help as some of these books have multiple subtitles, but I'd like to follow his suggestion if I can.

Comment: Oh, and I've tried specifying shorttitle={}, that didn't work. I'm also guessing putting a non-printing character in there would be a bad idea, as it would leave commas and such.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's easy to omit titles, but since they disambiguate entries hyperlinks are often applied to them. If you don't care about losing links something simple like

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{\clearfield{labeltitle}}{}}
```

would do the job with the standard `biblatex` styles. With `biblatex-chicago` absent fields generate spurious punctuation. Between that and the missing hyperlinks, you may as well redefine the `cite:short` macro. The code below gives an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

% Based on cite:short from chicago-notes.cbx
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR%
    \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{inreference}\OR%
    \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{reference}}
    {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{magazine}
       {\ifuseauthor
          {\printfield[journaltitle]{journaltitle}\isdot\newcunit}
          {}}
       {\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{manual}
          {\iffieldundef{organization}
             {}
             {\printlist{organization}\isdot\newcunit}}
          {}}%
     \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
    {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon}\OR%
       \iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon?}}
       {\bibleftbracket\\printnames{labelname}\bibrightbracket}
       {\printnames{labelname}}}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite{cicero}.
More filler text \autocite{cms}.
Even more filler text \autocite{bertram}. \pagebreak

\null\vfill
Filler text \autocites[19--20]{cicero}{bertram,cms}.
\end{document}
```

[image]